# Unable to install app via OTA on MDM (ios11.2.6)

Tags: ios, ios11, enterprise, mdm, app-distribution

We have enterprise app and we send updates of app via OTA.

I have two iPad device one is running ios 11.2.6 and other has 10.3.3
Both device configured with MDM having app installation restriction enabled

When I try to install app via OTA on 10.3.3 its working, but when I try with 11.2.6 nothings happens, installation not working.

Is that OS bug or something that we need to configure on device that running ios 11.2.6?

Comment: The logs on the device might reveal the problem. It's worth checking there.

Comment: Is the MDM command delivered to the device? check if the device is connected to internet.

Comment: I am not using MDM for installation. We use OTA to install update. And yes internet is working.

Comment: @Bin0li asked the right question.  If you're not using the MDM command to install it & have the app installation restriction in place, users will be unable to install the app as the restriction prevents them from doing UI app installation (which OTA falls under).  This was previously a bug in the restriction. You need to remove the restriction from the devices or install via MDM.